# Assign id to simple form collection options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

New developer trying to assign an different ids to Round Oval and Banana options, so can initiate action on select:

```
<%= f.input :content, label: 'Fruit Shape', :collection => %w[Round Oval Banana] %>
```

but all options always have the id 'update_content', I assume due to instance of Update.

```
$('#Round').on('click', function(){
    $("#round_div").show();
  })
```

Fails. From research I have tried:

```
:collection => %w[Round Oval Banana].map { |category| [category, {:id => category}]}
```

which generates

```
<select class="form-control select optional valid" name="update[content]" id="update_content" aria-invalid="false"><option value="">SELECT</option>
<option id="Round" value="Round">Round</option>
<option id="Oval" value="Oval">Oval</option>
<option id="Banana" value="Banana">Banana</option></select>
```

and other variations such as:

```
collection: [["Round", {:id => "round"}], ["Oval", {:id => "oval"}], ["Banana", {:id => "banana"}]],
```

but the round_div doesn't show